# Create simple starter menu QtQick/QML

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

I want to create menu of buttons in QML with simple animation
[Simple QML Menu](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ImTIM_8F8ROYYgLx7c4swldW_3ElI0T4/view)

When I add a button after another I only get the last one

Edit: I added this code also but everytime I click any button the menu disappears

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Menu {
           id: menu
            visible: true

           MenuItem {
              Button{
                  text:"Play"
              }
           }
           MenuItem {
               Button{
                   text:"Play"
               }
           }
           MenuItem {
               Button{
                   text:"Sett"
               }
           }
       }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

A [MenuItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-menuitem.html) already derives from AbstractButton, so there's no point in adding a Button as a child of the MenuItem.

The docs show many simple examples, like this:

```
    Menu {
        id: menu

        MenuItem {
            text: "New..."
            onTriggered: document.reset()
        }
        MenuItem {
            text: "Open..."
            onTriggered: openDialog.open()
        }
        MenuItem {
            text: "Save"
            onTriggered: saveDialog.open()
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's still disappearing after clicking any item and its not the one in the link at all

Comment: Why do you want a menu that stays open all the time. That's not usually how menus work. If you just want a vertical list of buttons, you can use a ListView for that.

Comment: It's  disappearing completely  I mean after 1 click on any item everything disappear